# Disabling ARC -- compiler flag already set

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag, but I still get an "ARC forbids message..." Here is a screenshot. Is there some other setting I need to change?

[image]

Comment: Have you cleaned your build (Cmd-K)?

Comment: Killed Xcode and rebooted the machine?

Comment: @Undo "Killed Xcode?" - "No, only whoever developed it."

Comment: @H2CO3 I like Xcode. Please don't kill me, but I would like to throw Eclipse into a volcano :)

Comment: @Undo I'm not defending Eclipse :) I hate most IDEs out there. My fav editor is Gedit, and I'm currently learning emacs.

Comment: @H2CO3 You misspelled `vi`.

Comment: Wait you meant "CMD+Shift+K" right? Xcode makes me want to quit developing. I only started down this path because no one answered my other question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972207/static-library-builds-in-debug-configuration-but-not-in-release-configuration

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao Yep. My bad. *Don't quit!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I wasn't copying these files into my project and just linking them from another project, the flag was not taking. When I check the "Copy items into destination folder" it worked.